# How to Triple boot

Tags: multi-boot

I have already dual boot on different HDD now I want install triple boot . On both HDD has Windows 7 I want install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS if I choose Install alongside Windows 7 then other OS Windows 7 will unused?

Comment: Why do you want to do so?

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath all OS will in use

Comment: Better go through [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156045/how-do-i-triple-boot-ubuntu-fedora-and-windows-7)

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath but ubuntu installer said already installed it I've preinstalled ubuntu , so if I reinstall ubuntu then it will boot all preinstalled all OS?

Answer (score 0):

Triple booting may be possible. But you want to plan this. First, backup your system. Because I have done double and triple boots and there is a LOT that can go wrong. So you should do a bare metal backup of the whole partition onto an external hard disk or the cloud or whatever you like. You must, must back up.

But I am not sure from the question exactly what you are trying to triple boot. A good site for discussing triple boots is:

http://www.dedoimedo.com/

though an archive article might have to be found in the site.

But I'd say that rather than triple booting have you considered using Virtualbox instead? You could run an OS in a  virtual way? That would be simpler and not risk your data and bootloader and so on. Again, the dedoimedo site has articles on virtualisation.

Sorry but I can't write a lot more. Triple booting 2 Linux partitions and 1 windows? Or 2 windows and 1 Linux? They would involve different considerations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really going for the 3 boot, BACK UP YOUR DATA FIRST. It is always important to backup in case something wrong happens. If you're getting a Linux distro, download the ISO. If you're getting a Windows OS, Get a DVD or ISO.

Second, shrink any partition to an available size so it doesn't take any memory.

For Linux, burn the ISO to a DVD, then insert your DVD inside your drive. Go to your boot settings and make sure you have boot from Boot from CD/DVD enabled. Follow the setup for your Linux distro's installation settings.

If you plan Windows, insert your DVD inside your drive and the setup should be there.
(Make sure before you run a Windows installation, check the system requirements.)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this. You'll boot into grub, which will let you select between linux and the windows bootloader. This will then boot into the windows 7 bootloader, which will let you select between installs.

Usual warnings count - backup before you do anything (a full disk image is what you WANT to do...) , its a good idea to resize, and have a windows partition as a first partition, remember that its 3 primary + extended (and you WILL need to do this, especially with modern installs of windows with many partitions) and so on. As such, I prefer to *manually* repartition with gparted, rather than using the automatic partitioner, and create and manually select partitions.