# How can I go about triple-booting with Windows 98 on my machine?

Tags: multi-boot, windows-10-preview, windows-98

I have an idea, but do not know if it will work.  I want to use Windows prior to XP, but, since Windows 2000 does not have a bootstrap method (at least, none that I can recall), I have decided upon using Windows 98.

I have two operating systems on this machine already, Ubuntu and Windows 10.  I also have a separate Data Partition.  Is it possible to run Windows 98 under Windows 10, as a program perhaps, or dual booted sharing one partition?  Or would I need something more complex?  Do I need another disc partition for Windows 98?

Note that I'm wanting to run it, when I bootstrap it, as the primary operating system on the bare metal, not virtualized.

[Triple-Boot + 4 partition Limit](https://superuser.com/questions/134230/) is a similar question, but note that I'm choosing Windows 98 as my third operating system, not Windows XP.  Similarly, [How to Triple boot](https://superuser.com/questions/784238/) deals with Windows 7, not Windows 98.

Comment: What? Can you please clarify what you are asking?

Comment: Edited for clarifcation

Comment: as a program?  no.  As a VM, yes.

Comment: Im not looking for VM solution.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/73767/dual-boot-nt4-and-windows-98?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something more complex - running 98 "as a program" is kind of an oxymoron - it's an OS. You can run 98 programs in a 98 VM using something like VirtualPC (I don't know the specifics for Win10 as I've not yet played with it), but you can't really run "Windows 98" as a program by itself.

And given your edit to the question which crossed my answer, you just need a new partition to install 98 to so that you chain boot to it the same way you chain boot to Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, you need a FAT16 partition if you want to bootstrap Windows 98

Comment: While I deny the fact 98 is a stand alone OS, you are right now the closest thing to a possible solution per bare metal.

Comment: Windows 98 is as much an OS as Windows 8 or Windows 2012. Or linux, or Mac OS X, or OS/2. If you seriously don't think it is, you don't know your computer history.